# How to save sortable elements positions in MVC .Net?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

how can I get all the item indexes and update and save it after it changes the position

```
<ul id="sortable"> 
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li> 
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li> 
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li> 
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li> 
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li> 
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 6</li> 
<li class="ui-state-default"><Item 7</li> 
</ul>




$("#sortable").sortable({
stop: function(event, ui) {
    alert("New position: " + ui.item.index());
}
```

Comment: Hi Giorgi - what do you mean exactly by save it? if you were to cycle through all of the li elements in the ul after a sort event you'll have up to date indexes - would you then like to store these updated indexes ?

Comment: @cookee89 HI thank for responding. After changing the positions of the items I want it to stay at that position after refresh or new log in but its a different job so right now more important is to me to get all the updated items positions when I sort it

Comment: If you want to persist items as you say you will need a mechanism to do so - you could use a cookie to store and update on a page refresh, or you could use a data store on the server side that you save to

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to display the updated positions of *all* the list items after a position change you could do the following

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
      update: function(event, ui) {
         var updatedPositions = "";
         $("#sortable li").each(function(idx, li){
         updatedPositions += $(li).html() + " New position: " + idx + '\n';
      })
      alert(updatedPositions)
    }
})
```

api docs can be found [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/)